# How do I push changes from one branch to another branch after a successful Jenkins build?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

How do I push changes from one branch to another branch after a successful Jenkins build?  Suppose I have a branch named "beta" that I commit to and another named "master" that I want to contain all commits to beta that are successful.

Answer (score 4):

From the Advanced Features section of the writeup for the Jenkins plugin available at the link at the bottom:

> Set up your Jenkins project, and leave the 'branch' field in the Git
>   SCM blank. This will cause Jenkins to consider any change on any
>   branch for building.
>
> Next, pick a particular branch name as the integration target in the
>   'Advanced' section - (e.g. 'master', or 'stable'), and select 'Merge
>   before build'.
>
> Select 'Push GIT tags back to origin repository' from the post-build
>   actions (this is required to update your centralised git repo with the
>   results of the build).
>
> Now, developers should never commit directly to your integration
>   branch (the 'master' or 'stable'). Instead, they should either use
>   feature branches, or create new remote branches on commit (e.g : "git
>   push origin HEAD:refs/heads/myNewFeature"). You could also set up your
>   GIT repository to only accept commits onto the integration branch from
>   Jenkins.
>
> You're done. Commits should now be automatically merged with the
>   integration branch (they will fail if they do not merge cleanly), and
>   built. If the build succeeds, the result of the merge will be pushed
>   back to the remote git repository.

A few elaborations based on my experience with the plugin:

1. I chose to create a branch named "beta" in my original repository.  Also, I decided that I only wanted to build when this branch was updated, so I set the "Branches to build" field to "*/beta".
2. I had to "Add an additional behaviour" of "merge before build" -- it wasn't just sitting there for me to select.  The name of the repository for me for this section was "origin" and the branch to merge to was "master".
3. I also selected a post-build action of "Git Publisher".  For this I checked both the box for "Push Only If Build Succeeds", and "Merge Results".  I also wrote "master" in the Branch to push box and "origin" in the target remote name.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin