# How can I automatically accept and merge a pull request in BitBucket after a successful Jenkins build?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

At the moment I'm using the BitBucket Build Pull Request plugin successfully. I want to tell BitBucket to accept and merge the PR (or merge the PR and push to BitBucket) on Jenkins success.

This answer

[How do I push changes from one branch to another branch after a successful Jenkins build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679691/how-do-i-push-changes-from-one-branch-to-another-branch-after-a-successful-jenki)

looks like it's on the right track, but it's old and isn't built with Jenkins 2 pipelines.

How would I achieve the same result with Jenkins 2?

Comment: I don't find a restful api of bitbucket to do so. I think you could do the merge and push in the repository cloned to the workspace of the Jenkins job.